# ext in buildscript can not be recognised by Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In these days, I am trying to write some codes to experience the Spring reactive features and kotlin extension in Spring 5, and I also prepared a  gradle Kotlin DSL build.gradle.kt to configure the gradle build.

The `build.gradle.kt` is converted from Spring Boot template codes generated by http://start.spring.io.

But the `ext` in the `buildscript` can not be detected by Gradle.

```
buildscript {
  ext { }
}
```

The `ext` will cause Gradle build error.

To make the variables in `classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")` and `compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlinVersion")` work, I added the variables in the hard way.

```
val kotlinVersion = "1.1.4"
val springBootVersion = "2.0.0.M3"
```

But I have to declare them in global top location and duplicate them in the `buildscript`.

Code: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/kotlin-gradle/build.gradle.kts

Is there a graceful approach to make `ext` work?

**Update**: There are some ugly approaches:

1. From Gradle Kotlin DSL example, https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/tree/master/samples/project-properties, declares the properties in gradel.properties.

   ```
    kotlinVersion = 1.1.4
    springBootVersion = 2.0.0.M3
   ```

   And use it in build.gradle.kts.

   ```
    buildScript{
       val kotlinVersion by project

    }
     val kotlinVersion by project //another declare out of buildscript block.
   ```
2. Similar with above declare them in buildScript block:

   ```
    buildScript{
       extra["kotlinVersion"] = "1.1.4"
       extra["springBootVersion"] = "2.0.0.M3"
       val kotlinVersion: String by extra

    }
     val kotlinVersion: String by extra//another declare out of buildscript block.
   ```

How can I avoid the duplication of **val kotlinVersion: String by extra**?

**Update**(2023-7-5): The latest Gradle supports `libs.versions.toml` file to declare dependency versions in a central place, it is also can be recognized by GitHub dependabot. see: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

Comment: I don't know how you can avoid the duplication, but you can join:
`extra["kotlinVersion"] = "1.1.4"
val kotlinVersion: String by extra`
to
`val kotlinVersion: String by extra("1.1.4")`

Comment: @ClausHolst Excellent clarification!

Answer (score 55):

With Kotlin DSL ext has been changed to extra and it can be used under buildscript.

Eg :-

```
buildscript {
    // Define versions in a single place
    extra.apply{
        set("minSdkVersion", 26)
        set("targetSdkVersion", 27)
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this work if I wanted to add a function to the extras object?

Comment: Can you add an example on how to use the property? Simply `implementation("org.library:library:$myVersion")` doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me in buildscript.

Comment: Reading extra properties:

`val myVersion: String by rootProject.extra`
`implementation("org.library:library:$myVersion")`

Comment: This is no way easier than using groovy, even when it does work...

Comment: But it's not just about constants of deps. What about shared configuration between modules? previously we could include `config_module.gradle` with `ext { android { ... } }` to each `build.gradle`. How can do it now?

Comment: Google uses this way for deps constants https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/main/buildSrc/src/main/java

Comment: Example for usage of 'extra' vars: 
`id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version extra.get("minSdkVersion") as String`

Answer (score 34):

It is possible to use constants defined in `.kt` file in `.gradle.kts` files.

create `buildSrc` folder in root folder of your project

create `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` file with the following content

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

create file `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Constants.kt` with the following content

```
object Constants {
    const val kotlinVersion = "1.3.70"
    const val targetSdkVersion = 28
}
```

Synchronize. Now you may reference created constants in various `.gradle.kts` files like this

```
...
classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = Constants.kotlinVersion))
...

...
targetSdkVersion(Constants.targetSdkVersion)
...
```

Comment: This works flawlessly, even for multi-module projects, and doesn't require ugly code in the buildscripts. Awesome!

Comment: Love this solution, thanks! Do you have any pointers on how to share buildSrc as an artifact so it can be reused between independent projects? Just a link to some doc would be fine, I'm just not sure where to start looking

Comment: @EmilKantis, sorry, don't know such solution. Try to search/ask here at StackOverflow

Comment: @EmilKantis buildSrc essentially works like a Gradle plugin that automatically gets applied to all the subprojects, so what you are looking to do is create a Gradle plugin. :)

Comment: The biggest problem I have with this is that the versions defined by `ext` in older iteration gradle files would work with the lint checker for new version libraries in e.g. Android Studio, but it does not work with these constants files, so you don't know if something has a newer version available (if you wanted to know)

Comment: But it's not just about constants of deps. What about shared configuration between modules? previously we could include `config_module.gradle` with `ext { android { ... } }` to each `build.gradle`. How can do it now?

Comment: @user924 use precompilled builds scripts https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-build-logic-with-kotlin-dsl-203274f73013

Comment: @EugenePopovich they require to set `"com.android.application"` or `"com.android.library"` to it could see `android` scope, which is not good, because previously I had one `common_config.gradle` for all modules (doesn't matter if it is app or library)

Comment: @EugenePopovich even with adding app or library plugin it won't compile such script `Unresolved reference: android`

Answer (score 26):

None of these answers felt clear to me.
So here's my explanation:

**/build.gradle.kts**:

```
buildscript {
    extra.apply {
        set("compose_version", "1.0.3")
    }
    ...
}
```

**/app/build.gradle.kts**:

```
val composeVersion = rootProject.extra["compose_version"]
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion")
implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion")
```

Answer (score 22):

What is working for me is using `ext` in `allprojects` instead of `buildscript`, so in your top-level `build.gradle.kts`

```
allprojects {
  ext {
    set("supportLibraryVersion", "26.0.1")
  }
}
```

then you can use it in `build.gradle.kts` files in modules like this:

```
val supportLibraryVersion = ext.get("supportLibraryVersion") as String
```

Comment: Or slightly more concise:

`val supportLibraryVersion : String? by ext`

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: wrong and ugly, should be https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/main/buildSrc/src/main/java

Comment: @user924 oh yes, an extra Gradle module slowing down everything just to have constants.

Comment: @NinoDELCEY it's official Google way, at least it looks normal

Comment: in your example you use magic strings

Comment: @NinoDELCEY all MVVM solutions have similar implementation, not just on Android platform. Anyway we can now switch to declarative UI (Jetpack Compose) and Google made it good, mb it's even better than SwiftUI

Comment: @user924 Just because few developers at google did it that way doesn't mean it is "Google way"

Comment: BTW, can you define why you think it is "wrong"?

Answer (score 16):

There is a new possibility with Kotlin we can use:

```
object DependencyVersions {
    const val JETTY_VERSION = "9.4.12.v20180830"
}

dependencies{
    implementation("org.eclipse.jetty:jettyserver:${DependencyVersions.JETTY_VERSION}")
}
```

Here, DependencyVersions is a name I chose. You can choose another name, 
like "MyProjectVariables". This is a way to avoid using the extra or ext properties.

Comment: I think using a companion object would be more idiomatic kotlin style

Comment: @MattKerr not at all, if you need a singleton, you should use `object`

Comment: Can you reference this in subprojects though?

Answer (score 6):

Global properties in kotlin-gradle-dsl:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53594357/3557894

---

Kotlin version is embedded into kotlin-gradle-dsl. 
You can use dependecies with embedded version as follows:

```
implementation(embeddedKotlin("stdlib-jdk7"))

classpath(embeddedKotlin("gradle-plugin"))
```

Comment: the newer way is to add to plugins: `kotlin("jvm")` and to deps: `implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8")`

Answer (score 4):

```kotlin
val junitVersion by extra("4.13.2")
testImplementation("junit:junit:$junitVersion")
```

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, the way to do this is with `by extra` or an `ext` block.

With `by extra`:

```kotlin
val kotlinVersion = "95" by extra
val kotlinCompiler = true by extra
```

With `ext`:

```kotlin
ext {
    set("kotlinVersion", "95")
    set("kotlinCompiler", true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Between, from latest code style above will not work, only with some bits and pieces. However, added a `plugins` block if someone needs a way to handle the same in the `.kts` file system.

**/build.gradle.kts:**

```
buildscript {
    extra.apply {
        set("compose_ui_version", "1.2.0")
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.4.0" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.4.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.7.0" apply false
}
```

**/app/build.gradle.kts:**

```
dependencies {
    val composeUiVersion = rootProject.extra["compose_ui_version"]
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeUiVersion")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$composeUiVersion")
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$composeUiVersion")
    debugImplementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$composeUiVersion")
    debugImplementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$composeUiVersion")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it like this:

```
val kotlinVersion by extra("1.1.4")
```

Use it like this:

```
val kotlinVersion: String by rootProject.extra
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a possibility to define global properties within gradle.properties:

```
xyzVersion=1.0.0
```

And then use them in your module's build.gradle.kts:

```
val xyzVersion: String by project
```

Comment: You could also just skip the additional variable declaration and just access the variable  directly in your dependency: `implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:${project.ext["io_ktor_version"]}")`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the best way is to use Version Catalogs. You define a versionCatalogs in settings.gradle.kts, describe every required library in it, add a label to each library, and then use that library label in build.gradle files.

For example:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            library("rxandroid", "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0")
            library("rxjava", "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.4")
            library("commons-lang3", "org.apache.commons", "commons-lang3").version {
                strictly("[3.8, 4.0[")
                prefer("3.9")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then sync you project, so labels will be generated.
and then add to your build.gragle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.rxjava)
    implementation(libs.rxandroid)
    implementation(libs.commons.lang3)
}
```

And you can move versionCatalogs to separate file and then include it. And you can use separate object with lib versions, if you like:

dependency.gradle.kts:

```
object LibVersions {
    const val rxJava =    "2.2.4"
    const val rxAndroid = "2.1.0"
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            library("rxandroid", "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${LibVersions.rxAndroid}")
            library("rxjava", "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${LibVersions.rxAndroid}")
            library("timber", "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1")
        }
    }
}
```

settings.gradle.kts

```
buildscript {
    apply("dependency.gradle.kts")
}
```

You can read more here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

Comment: It is similar to use the `libs.versions.toml` file, but we can not set the exclude in the library directly.