# Kotlin DSL: Import a versions.gradle.kts into another build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have created a `versions.gradle.kts` just like that:

```
object Defines {
     const val kotlinVersion = "1.2.61"
     const val junitVersion = "5.3.0"
}
```

Now I want to import and use that files like that:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

group = "io.github.deglans"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version Defines.kotlinVersion
}

application {
    mainClassName = "io.github.deglans.polishnotation.MainKt"
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter", "junit-jupiter-api", Defines.junitVersion)
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter", "junit-jupiter-engine", Defines.junitVersion)
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

How can I do that?

NOTE:
I have already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753733/ext-in-buildscript-can-not-be-recognised-by-gradle-kotlin-dsl) but it is not exactly that I search...

Comment: Two things are not clear for me: 1) Why do you define the version in the separate file? Wouldn't be enough to define the versions e.g. in the `gradle.properties` file? Or in the `extra` (ExtraPropertiesExtension)? 2) Why do you want to wrap those versions inside the `Defines` object? Why not to use just simple plain `val`s?

Answer (score 8):

While I think it should be possible to import another `gradle.kts` file, I couldn't get it to work properly.

However, I did manage to define my dependencies in a separate Kotlin file in the `buildSrc` directory.

1. Create a `buildSrc` folder in the root of your project (same level as `build.gradle.kts`)
2. Add a `build.gradle.kts` in that `buildSrc` folder. Here, you need to define the `kotlin-dsl` plugin. You also need to define the repository where to get the plugin.

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

3. Create a Kotlin file where you define your dependencies in `src/main/kotlin` inside the `buildSrc`folder. You need to create a normal Kotlin `.kt` file, not a `gradle.kts`.

Reimport your Gradle config and you can now use the variables you defined in your Kotlin file created in step #3 in your `build.gradle.kts`.

Comment: i think that is related to the case when using/including the versions.gradle.kts into a build.gradle.kts.
i have a similar issue, in this case (outside of this question) is related to include plugin configs into build.gradle.kts files -- using the function apply from .gradle/groovy or similar