# How can I define an ext property from Heap.io with gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-gradle-plugin-3.3.0, heap.io

Im using the [heap.io](https://heap.io/) and their [Android SDK](https://help.heap.io/getting-started/installation-guides/android/) and they advise you to setup their library like:

- `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Add this section to enable Heap event capture.
        ext {
          heapEnabled = true
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

But this is using the gradle groovy sintax, Im trying to use it with the Kotlin DSL of gradle like:

- `build.gradle.kts`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ext {
            set("heapEnabled", true)
        }
```

But it does not work for some reason, so:

Why that may be happening?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927378/247325

Comment: This already have an answer, but thanks

Comment: Using the groovyBuilder defeats the whole purpose of using kts :(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to make it work using `withGroovyBuilder` like:

```kotlin
android {
    defaultConfig {
        withGroovyBuilder {
            "ext" {
                setProperty("heapEnabled", LhConfig.isAnalyticEnabled(project))
            }
        }
```

I still dont understand where is the issue :(

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
(this as ExtensionAware).extensions.extraProperties.set("heapEnabled", true)
```

I believe Heap is looking into making it so the cast isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

extra.set("heapEnabled", false)