# Unresolved reference: ext when convert gradle to gradle.kts

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

By default when I create a compose app from Android Studio, it will give me `ext` as below in my root project `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

As I change it to `build.gradle.kts`, it will complaint

```
Unresolved reference: ext
Unresolved reference: compose_version
Too many characters in a character literal ''1.0.0''
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927378/8826599 Cheers

Answer (score 8):

I use

```
buildscript {
    extra.apply{
        set("compose_version", "1.0.0")
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

To access it from other `gradle` files, I need to explicitly set to a variable

```
val composeVersion = rootProject.extra.get("compose_version") as String
```

Then I can use it like

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = composeVersion
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
   implementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion")
}
```

Comment: `val composeVersion = rootProject.extra["compose_version"]` is an alternative

Answer (score 2):

Set it like this:

```
val composeVersion by extra("1.0.0")
```

Use it like this:

```
val composeVersion: String by rootProject.extra
```

Groovy allows you to use single quotes for strings, but Kotlin requires double quotes. Change all the strings in your kts files to use double quotes to get rid of the `Too many characters in a character literal` error.