# Could not get unknown property 'extra' for object of type DefaultScriptHandler

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I try to convert gradle file into kotlin script file:
`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0'
    }
}
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.4.0" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.4.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.7.0" apply false
}
```

I refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69323792/14887783):
`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
buildscript {
    extra.apply{
        set("compose_version", "1.2.0")
    }
}
```

but not working:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Sage'.
> Could not get unknown property 'extra' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
```

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using? What is the code that gets the `compose_version` variable?

Comment: @aSemy Gradle 7.6 or 7.4. This is declaring variable, not getting variable.